# Space before heading larger than space after heading with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

In renderings of HTML code like

```
<p>Paragraph 1.</p>
<h3>Heading</h3>
<p>Paragraph 2.</p>
```

I would like to have slightly more vertical space before the heading than after the heading. Reason: the heading should semantically belong more to the second paragraph than to the first one. Of course, both space values should exceed the usual interline-spacing. The exact amount of space and the way to render it (if the client decides to render the vertical space at all) should be left to the client (browser, [braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille) device, printer, speech engine, etc.) to create a pleasant output.

My best try so far for my machine is

```
<p style="margin-bottom:3ex">Paragraph 1.</p>
<h3>Heading</h3>
<p>Paragraph 2.</p>
```

However, I'm feeling uncomfortable in hardcoding the exact value as it might probably look well for similar setups as my machine, but not universally. Any better suggestions with HTML and CSS? (If possible, don't use more stuff than HTML and CSS: I'd like my page to be intelligible for as many clients as possible.)

In essence, I wish the to have an HTML+CSS solution whose effect on spacing before/after the heading is roughly the same as that of the following pseudocode:

```
if(vertical_space_before <= vertical_space_after) {
  mean_vertical_space := (vertical_space_before + vertical_space_after)/2;
  vertical_space_before := 1.1*mean_vertical_space;
  vertical_space_after := 0.9*mean_vertical_space;
}
```

Comment: if my answer solved it, please mark it as correct (green check).

Comment: You can use media queries to be sure no screen size looks funny.

Comment: Nope. Just breaking points. How do think everyone does it? You: 1. reduce size till it looks bad. 2. add a query, 3. Repeat. You can use Chrome to resize slowly and watch for bad stuff.

Comment: I'd be surprised. And probably jobless.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/kqun2wbo/2/

CSS:

```css
p {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
h3 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<p>Paragraph 1.</p>
<h3>Heading</h3>
<p>Paragraph 2.</p>
```

Comment: Yes. With HTML and CSS only, the only other things you can use are: %, and queries. None of which *really* apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Change your header CSS content, not the *[p](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)* tag. Initially reset all margins and padding from your content page or panel and after that using *margin-bottom* and *margin-top* are fair enough to do to achieve this.

```css
.container {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-top: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

p {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
<div class='container'>
  <hr>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pro brute altera vidisse ea, mea eu meis audiam efficiantur. Malorum volutpat ut est. Cu iuvaret ullamcorper duo, duo placerat salutandi ut. Sensibus democritum vis ex. Expetendis neglegentur voluptatibus ut sea, quo in vitae omnium, mel noster latine ei.</p>
  <h3>Being More Elegant</h3>
  <p>Timeam efficiendi ut vis, in iisque aeterno qui. Sea cu quando detraxit. Sit ut fastidii deleniti temporibus, eos et apeirian elaboraret. Ei per commodo habemus. Ad quo adipisci moderatius.</p>
</div>
```

If you are asking for the different browsers and screen size, you can use the [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

Using a simple media query, you can try the below code block.

```css
@media only screen /* Portrait IPhone 6+ */
and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait) {
    h3 {
        font-size: 28px;
        margin-top: 14px;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
    }
}

@media only screen /* Landscape IPhone 6+ */
and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape) {
    h3 {
        font-size: 22px;
        margin-top: 7px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
}
```

Comment: @LeonMeier What do you mean with 'default browser's choices'. Are you trying to say; you want to show different vertical size in mobile browsers and desktop browsers?

Comment: I know this is tedious but that's the coding and programming. Another solution is javascript. You can get screen size or anything else with js and type your all css dynamically but it is actually the same solution with css query. There is no way to adapt css codes for new devices until you type code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out [this fluid type scale calculator](https://utopia.fyi/type/calculator/), use that to set font sizes. Then use the `stack` utility class by Andy Bell:

```
.stack > * + * {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

This will make font sizes responsive and adapt to the viewport width, and add spacing to the top of elements inside the `.stack`, the spacing will be relative to each elements font-size, so for headings larger than paragraph text, the spacing will be larger above than below.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

h1 { font-size: 4rem; }

h2 { font-size: 2rem; }

.stack > * + * {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="stack">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <h2>Dolor sit amet</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<p style="line-height:450%;">Paragraph 1.</p>
<h3>Heading</h3>
<p>Paragraph 2.</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lt50jysy/

Comment: So use `margin-bottom` instead